# How to add a class to a menu item that has children

Tags: jquery, html, css

I just created menu and some of the items have sub items as you can see on my html structure:

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
  <div class="menu-menu-1-container">
    <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu">
      <li id="menu-item-41" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-4 current_page_item menu-item-41">
        <a href="http://powersol.burnnotice.co.za/">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-42" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-42">
        <a href="http://powersol.burnnotice.co.za/our-dealers/">Our Dealers</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-250" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-250">
            <a href="http://powersol.burnnotice.co.za/dealer-1/">Dealer 1</a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-246" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-246">
            <a href="http://powersol.burnnotice.co.za/dealer-2/">Dealer 2</a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-245" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-245">
            <a href="http://powersol.burnnotice.co.za/dealer-3/">Dealer 3</a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-249" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-249">
            <a href="http://powersol.burnnotice.co.za/dealer-4/">Dealer 4</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-39" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-39">
        <a href="http://powersol.burnnotice.co.za/companies/">Companies</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-247" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-247">
            <a href="http://powersol.burnnotice.co.za/companies-1/">Companies 1</a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-253" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-253">
            <a href="http://powersol.burnnotice.co.za/companies-3/">Companies 3</a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-248" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-248">
            <a href="http://powersol.burnnotice.co.za/companies-4/">Companies 4</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-40" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-40">
        <a href="http://powersol.burnnotice.co.za/contact/">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>        
</nav>
```

For the css, I first put a display none cause initially the sub-menus cannot be visible.

```
.main-navigation ul li{
    display: none;
}
```

Now, How can I add a class dropdown-menu to a menu item that has sub-items everytime I hover over that particular item?

Here my js but it does nothing when I hover over the item:

```
$('.main-navigation ul > li.menu-item-has-children').on("hover" function(){
    $('.main-navigation ul > li.menu-item-has-children').removeClass('dropdown-menu');
    if($(this).hasClass('dropdown-menu')){
        $(this).addClass('dropdown-menu');
    }else{
        $(this).addClass('dropdown-menu');
    }
});
```

[Here my pen if needed](http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/BQxYvB)

Comment: add working fiddle please

Comment: you can simply do with this css, why dont you use css:hover here ,

Comment: @Jishnu V S If I use css hover, all the sub menus will drop-down at the same every time I hover a list that has sub items. And then again remember that there is no hover property on mobile devices

Comment: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3eejs6ws/), Hope this will work for you.

Comment: As a side note: `.on("hover", handler)` is removed, use instead `.on("mouseenter", handler)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this demo ,only use css, check the dropdown, this only for your information

```css
#primary-menu > li {
 display:inline-block;
 position:relative;
 margin:15px;
}
#primary-menu > li ul {
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 padding:0;
 display:none;
}
#primary-menu > li ul li {
 white-space:nowrap;
}
#primary-menu > li:hover ul {
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
  <div class="menu-menu-1-container">
    <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu">
      <li id="menu-item-41" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-4 current_page_item menu-item-41">
        <a href="http://powersol.burnnotice.co.za/">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-42" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-42">
        <a href="http://powersol.burnnotice.co.za/our-dealers/">Our Dealers</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-250" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-250">
            <a href="http://powersol.burnnotice.co.za/dealer-1/">Dealer 1</a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-246" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-246">
            <a href="http://powersol.burnnotice.co.za/dealer-2/">Dealer 2</a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-245" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-245">
            <a href="http://powersol.burnnotice.co.za/dealer-3/">Dealer 3</a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-249" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-249">
            <a href="http://powersol.burnnotice.co.za/dealer-4/">Dealer 4</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-39" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-39">
        <a href="http://powersol.burnnotice.co.za/companies/">Companies</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-247" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-247">
            <a href="http://powersol.burnnotice.co.za/companies-1/">Companies 1</a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-253" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-253">
            <a href="http://powersol.burnnotice.co.za/companies-3/">Companies 3</a>
          </li>
          <li id="menu-item-248" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-248">
            <a href="http://powersol.burnnotice.co.za/companies-4/">Companies 4</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-40" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-40">
        <a href="http://powersol.burnnotice.co.za/contact/">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>        
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it CSS `:hover` itself. but as you wanted in `jquery` here is the solution

Use `$('.main-navigation ul > li.menu-item-has-children').on("mouseenter mouseleave",  function(e){`. `mouseenter mouseleave` in place of `hover`

```js
$('.main-navigation ul > li.menu-item-has-children').on("mouseenter mouseleave",  function(e){
    $('.main-navigation ul > li.menu-item-has-children').removeClass('dropdown-menu');
    if(e.type=='mouseenter')
    $(this).addClass('dropdown-menu');
});
```

```css
.main-navigation ul ul{
    display: none;
}
.main-navigation ul li.dropdown-menu ul{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
    <div class="menu-menu-1-container">
    <ul id="primary-menu" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-41" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-4 current_page_item menu-item-41">
            <a href="http://powersol.burnnotice.co.za/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-42" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-42">
            <a href="http://powersol.burnnotice.co.za/our-dealers/">Our Dealers</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-250" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-250">
                    <a href="http://powersol.burnnotice.co.za/dealer-1/">Dealer 1</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-246" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-246">
                    <a href="http://powersol.burnnotice.co.za/dealer-2/">Dealer 2</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-245" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-245">
                    <a href="http://powersol.burnnotice.co.za/dealer-3/">Dealer 3</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-249" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-249">
                    <a href="http://powersol.burnnotice.co.za/dealer-4/">Dealer 4</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-39" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-39">
            <a href="http://powersol.burnnotice.co.za/companies/">Companies</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-247" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-247">
                    <a href="http://powersol.burnnotice.co.za/companies-1/">Companies 1</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-253" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-253">
                    <a href="http://powersol.burnnotice.co.za/companies-3/">Companies 3</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-248" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-248">
                    <a href="http://powersol.burnnotice.co.za/companies-4/">Companies 4</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-40" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-40">
            <a href="http://powersol.burnnotice.co.za/contact/">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>        
</nav>
```